# Outlook doesn't show newly added or deleted attachments while editing a message

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, office365

We're using Outlook 2013 from our Office365 subscription with an exchange online mailserver.

a co-worker (which works on win7) has a problem with editing e-mail messages, especially when adding or deleting attachments.

let's say the co-worker received a mail with one PDF attached. he now wants to add two more PDF to the mail. he's drag & dropping the PDFs into the mail, but they don't show up in the attachment part. if he now saves his edit, closes the e-mail and reopens it, all three PDF are attached to the mail

same for deleting attachments: if he deletes one of the 3 PDF attachments, it won't show instantly that it's gone, he has to save and reopen the mail to see his changes.

What could cause Outlook to not "auto-refresh" while editing the mail, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this behavior. I'm not sure what would be the cause.  But usually, it's something in the local profile or due to add-ons in Outlook. It is also possible it could be any anti-malware services they are running.

I would run the recovery assistant tool:https://diagnostics.outlook.com/#/?env=ExRCA

See if it finds and fixes anything.  If it continues to be a problem I would then disable all add-ons, and finally, I would remove their mail profile and configure a new one.